# How to check the success of AJAX request for following chunk of code using Drupal.ajax()

Tags: ajax, javascript

The following code makes and AJAX request using Drupal.ajax() function. What I want is to have some kind of callback that will be executed once the request completed, basically the 'success' parameter of usual jQuery AJAX request. Adding `success = function(request, status)` parameter doesn't help either, or maybe I did something wrong ther. So how could I get a success callback to this request?

```
var ajaxSettings = {
    url: eventEditFormUrl + '/nojs',
    selector: popContClass + '>div.content',
    wrapper: popContClass + '>div.content',
    event: 'add_event',
    method: 'html',
    progress: {
        type: 'none',
    },
    speed: 'fast',
    effect: 'fade',
};
var req = new Drupal.ajax(null, popContClass, ajaxSettings);
$(popContClass).trigger('add_event');
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more information on why the success function didn't work for you or what code you were using for it? This should work exactly like ajax settings in jquery Ajax since its just a passthrough, so your code would be something like this in your js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: eventEditFormUrl + '/nojs',
    selector: popContClass + '>div.content',
    wrapper: popContClass + '>div.content',
    event: 'add_event',
    method: 'html',
    progress: {
        type: 'none',
    },
    speed: 'fast',
    effect: 'fade',
    success: function(){
       $(this).html("woot.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to call javascript commands that are invoked via [Ajax framework commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7), Drupal uses a `success` callback (see the code in [misc/ajax.js](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/misc/ajax.js#l158) on HEAD of 7.x branch). Therefore if you specify your own `success` callback in settings for `Drupal.ajax`, no Drupal Ajax framwork commands will be executed.

In order to execute a custom code in `success` callback and leave Drupal Ajax framwork workings intact, you need to override the default Drupal Ajax framework's `success` callback with the one that executes both your code and that of Drupal Ajax framework, but you need to create Drupal.ajax object first.

Example:

```
var ajaxSettings = {
    // your settings here
};

// Initiate Drupal.ajax object
var req = new Drupal.ajax(null, element, ajaxSettings);

// Override success callback
req.options.success = function (response, status) {
  // Place your code here
  // your_code_here();

  // Proceed with default "success" callback code from Drupal Ajax framework

  // Sanity check for browser support (object expected).
  // When using iFrame uploads, responses must be returned as a string.
  if (typeof response == 'string') {
    response = $.parseJSON(response);
  }
  return req.success(response, status);
}

// Trigger event here
```

Another (and technically better) option is to call "success" callback code directly using `call()` method. This avoids code repetition.

```
var ajaxSettings = {
    // your settings here
};

// Initiate Drupal.ajax object
var req = new Drupal.ajax(null, element, ajaxSettings);

// Override success callback
req.options.success = function (response, status) {
  // Place your code here
  // your_code_here();

  // Call original method with main functionality
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.success.call(req, response, status);
}

// Trigger event here
```

Credit for the last approach goes to [asghar](https://drupal.org/user/415797) as he described it in [related topic](https://drupal.org/node/1028410#comment-7780409) on [drupal.org](https://drupal.org).